# Invalid Object Name for Temp Table in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I'm trying to use a temp table to update a database table in a stored procedure.

My client was throwing an error about an illegal null value, so I tried testing within SSMS and it told me that the name of the temp table was invalid (regardless of what I named it).

If I run the beginning and change the `INSERT INTO SERVICE SELECT S.*` to simply `SELECT S.*` and run the code after Declaring and Defining @OldServicesString (so I can leave out the `ALTER/CREATE PROCEDURE` line) it runs exactly as expected.

Here's the beginning of the SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[app_CreateNewServicesOldFSD] (@OldServicesStr nvarchar(max)) AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @User char(10) = (SELECT TOP 1 CREATED_BY_USER FROM BATCHLOG WHERE BPROCESS_ID = 3 ORDER BY ID DESC);
DECLARE @LastOldService int = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM SERVICE);

SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #Service FROM SERVICE;
ALTER TABLE #Service
DROP COLUMN RECNUM;
INSERT INTO #Service exec dbo.app_NewServicesOldFSD

;WITH cteOldFSDsToCreate AS (
    SELECT JobID.Item JobID, CONVERT(date,ServDate.Item,103) ServDate
    FROM dbo.SplitStringToTable(@OldServicesStr,',',2) JobID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SplitStringToTable(@OldServicesStr,',',2) ServDate ON JobID.Rw = ServDate.Rw AND JobID.Cl = 0 AND ServDate.Cl = 1
)

INSERT INTO SERVICE SELECT S.*
FROM #Service S
INNER JOIN cteOldFSDsToCreate N ON N.JobID = S.JOB_ID AND N.ServDate = S.DATE

DROP TABLE #Service
```

A useable and likely @OldServicesStr could be '11428,23/07/2019,11429,23/07/2019,15186,5/10/2019'

To test it in SSMS I opened a new Query and typed in 
`exec app_CreateNewServicesOldFSD '11428,23/07/2019,11429,23/07/2019,15186,5/10/2019'`

And got the following error:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure app_CreateNewServicesOldFSD, Line 65 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Invalid object name '#Service'. 
> Completion time: 2020-11-20T20:36:57.1356921+11:00

Comment: What is the *actual* error you are getting.

Comment: @Larnu Just updated the question. Oddly when I first tried it parsed #Service as 'TempService' automatically. This time the error reads verbatim.

Comment: The first message is a warning, to *remind* you that `NULL` values aren't included in aggregate functions. For the latter, what line is Line 65? There aren't 65 lines in the above.

Comment: @Larnu goodness I feel silly - I checked line 65 and didn't find anything, but I must have had a boys look. I only included this part of the SP because I didn't think `#Service` appeared anywhere else, but I missed where it did when I checked (poorly, apparently) line 65. I'll double check it's all working and then nuke my own question...

Answer (score 0):

I know that is not Your case but in the sake of not forget, there is also a limitation using Biztalk WCF-Custom adapter with SQL Bindings and temp tables.

According to this site :
http://thoughtsofmarcus.blogspot.com/2010/11/calling-stored-procedures-from-biztalk.html

You need to SET FMTONLY OFF before creating temp tables and inserting into them and
SET FMTONLY ON before selecting from them as in example from below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchTestData]
(@a4 varchar(4))
AS
DECLARE @FmtOnlyIsSet bit = 0
IF (1=0) BEGIN SET @FmtOnlyIsSet = 1 END
IF @FmtOnlyIsSet = 1
   SET FMTONLY OFF

SELECT t1, t2, t3 INTO #temp01 FROM Table_1

IF @FmtOnlyIsSet IS NULL
   SET FMTONLY ON

SELECT t1, t2, t3 FROM #temp01

RETURN
```